# Flutter bottom overflowed by pixel with column

Tags: flutter, mobile, layout, flutter-layout

I am following a Flutter course on Udemy but I can't understand how fix this problem.

Code:

```
      body: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
          child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ReusableCard(
              onPress: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectedGender = Gender.male;
                });
              },
              colour: selectedGender == Gender.male
                  ? kActiveCardColour
                  : kInactiveCardColour,
              cardChild: IconContent(
                icon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                label: 'MALE',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ReusableCard(
              onPress: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectedGender = Gender.female;
                });
              },
              colour: selectedGender == Gender.female
                  ? kActiveCardColour
                  : kInactiveCardColour,
              cardChild: IconContent(
                icon: FontAwesomeIcons.venus,
                label: 'FEMALE',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
      Expanded(
        child: ReusableCard(
          colour: kActiveCardColour,
          cardChild: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'HEIGHT',
                style: kLabelTextStyle,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    height.toString(),
                    style: kNumberTextStyle,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'cm',
                    style: kLabelTextStyle,
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SliderTheme(
                data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                  inactiveTrackColor: Color(0xFF8D8E98),
                  activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
                  thumbColor: Color(0xFFEB1555),
                  overlayColor: Color(0x29EB1555),
                  thumbShape:
                      RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 15.0),
                  overlayShape:
                      RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 30.0),
                ),
                child: Slider(
                  value: height.toDouble(),
                  min: 120.0,
                  max: 220.0,
                  onChanged: (double newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      height = newValue.round();
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ReusableCard(
                colour: kActiveCardColour,
                cardChild: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'WEIGHT',
                      style: kLabelTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      weight.toString(),
                      style: kNumberTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        RoundIconButton(
                            icon: FontAwesomeIcons.minus,
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                weight--;
                              });
                            }),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10.0,
                        ),
                        RoundIconButton(
                          icon: FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              weight++;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ReusableCard(
                colour: kActiveCardColour,
                cardChild: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'AGE',
                      style: kLabelTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      age.toString(),
                      style: kNumberTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        RoundIconButton(
                          icon: FontAwesomeIcons.minus,
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(
                              () {
                                age--;
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10.0,
                        ),
                        RoundIconButton(
                            icon: FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                age++;
                              });
                            })
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      BottomButton(
        buttonTitle: 'CALCULATE',
        onTap: () {
          CalculatorBrain calc =
              CalculatorBrain(height: height, weight: weight);

          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ResultsPage(
                    bmiResult: calc.calculateBMI(),
                    resultText: calc.getResult(),
                    interpretation: calc.getInterpretation(),
                  ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

This is the file:
https://github.com/londonappbrewery/BMI-Calculator-Flutter-Completed/blob/master/lib/screens/input_page.dart

On the emulator it works correctly but on my Galaxy S7 there are some errors:
[image: Error image]

I have tried different solutions for example wrap my main column inside a `SingleChildScrollView` but it's not working.

Is it possible to use a scrollbar or something?

Or I have to use a ListView instead? In that case, there are no properties like `mainAxisAlignment` or `crossAxisAlignment`.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the relevant code directly into the question.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore done

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your **ReusableCard** with a Container and a FittedBox:

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard({@required this.colour, this.cardChild, this.onPress});

  final Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
        child: FittedBox(
          child: cardChild,
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The result:

[image]

[image]

You can adjust the size of the Container if you need, based on the width or height of the current device.

Comment: Thanks! I also found another solution:
use ListView instead of Column and wrap every single child of Rows inside Expanded widget.